# Set builder notation verify correctness

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I want to show this?

$\{x|x\neq\frac{2}{3} \text{ and } x \neq 2\}$

Is this the most eloquent way of saying this? Or is there a more correct form in set builder notation?

Thanks.

Comment: That seems consise, if you want to say the set of everything except 2/3 and 2 .  You may also want to include the implicit universe (real numbers? rationals?).

Comment: Can you show me how that is written in an answer @GrahamKemp ? For example for real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems consise, if you want to say the set of everything except 2/3 and 2 .  You may also want to include the implicit universe (real numbers? rationals?).

Eg:- $$\Bbb R\smallsetminus\{\tfrac 23,2\}~=~\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x\neq \tfrac 23\land x\neq 2\}$$

Comment: Oh nice, so I could have said $\Bbb R\smallsetminus\{\tfrac 23,2\}$ thankyou very much @GrahamKemp